# Using 'boot2docker ip' in your database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, boot2docker

I'd like to use something like the following in my database.yml:

```
host: %x(boot2docker ip)
```

However, whenever I do this, I get back something like the following error:

`RuntimeError (YAML syntax error occurred while parsing ...-database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 12 column 9):`

It seems clear to me that it's something about the way that boot2docker is responding with the ip is wrong, adding a newline or similar. I could put this somewhere else, but it seems right just to do it inline - is there an elegant (one line) way to do this?

Comment: Or that yaml files aren't just Ruby files.

Comment: @DaveNewton right, but rails does do some interpretation - eg it supports template structures

Comment: sounds like a yaml syntax error, verify your yaml with yaml validator or yamllint

Comment: is the line that you reference, host: %x..., line 12?

Comment: if you put in an ip address in there, like host: 10.10.10.10, does the error go away or still occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that database.yml is not a ruby file, it is just raw yml, in which templating works. If I want to execute ruby, I need to escape it.

The answer here was the following:

```
host: <%= %x(boot2docker ip) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your yaml parser needs a double quote:

```
host: "%x(boot2docker ip)"
```